# NGINX location wildcard

Tags: nginx

We have multiple subfolders under `public_html` which basically just go

- /year2014
- /year2015
- ...

Can I do an nginx conf.d location wildcard like so and how?

```
 location /year2014 {
     rewrite ^/year2014 /(/.*)$ /app/webroot$1 break;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /year2014 /app/webroot/index.php?$args;
 }
```

Can I turn location /year2014 as a wildcard variable meaning it can be anything because all these share the same setting?

Comment: When you say "have multiple subfolders" do you mean physical directories inside `public_html` or is it just your URI structure?

Comment: Yes, physical directories

Answer (score 0):

How about this (not tested)? Note the location changes to root and the double rewrite rule to cover for slash at the end.

```
location / {
     rewrite "^/year(.*)" /app/webroot/year$1/;
     rewrite "^/year(.*)/" /app/webroot/year$1/;
...
```

Comment: `rewrite ^/year(.*)(?:\/)` might work for both?